# Fast implementation for pairwise short string segment comparison problem

Tags: c, algorithm

I wonder if there are any algorithms or libraries that can speed up the following calculation:

> Given input data with m sequences length n, return a scoring auxiliary
>   matrix, the value is calculated by the number of total matches of
>   every segment pairs  S_ij and S_pq, where i,p will iterate all rows; 
>   j,q will iterate all columns in the original matrix.

For example, the input has 2 sequences and each sequence has a length of 16. For the two segments of length=8, S_13 and S_25 highlighted in bold, their number of matches is 8.

AA**TTCCGGAA**TTCCGG

CCCC**TTCCGGAA**TTCC

For S_13 and S_26, the number of matches is 4

AA**TTCCGGAA**TTCCGG

CCCCT**TCCGGAAT**TCC

The goal is to obtain such a number of matches matrix for every position. I tried the iteration of all positions, which is 4 **for** loops i,p,j,q. I also tried first obtain all k-mer pairs and calculate their number of matches, however, it's very slow, I wonder if there are any ways to speed up the calculations?

Comment: You should share your current attempt to help others to have a working implementation.

Comment: For many columns, this can be speeded up by about a factor of the substring length: After counting matches in an initial substring pairing, iteratively compute the count for successive substrings (moved one column to the right in both of the candidates) by adding the number of matches (0 or 1) in the incoming pair of characters and subtracting the number of matches (0 or 1) in the outgoing pair.

Comment: This can be speeded up with SIMD code: Represent the 4 character possibilities using two bits. Store one bit for each character in one array (or vector block) and the other in another. Then comparisons between string A with bits a0 and a1 and string B with bits b0 and b1 using (a0 ^ b0) | (a1 ^ b1), in which each bit will be 0 iff the corresponding characters are equal. Then various bit-shifting and horizontal adds can be used to count the matches.

Comment: Those two techniques are not independent, so they might not be combinable or might be only partially combinable. I do not see much hope for improvement in the computational complexity as knowing the number of matches between row i and j and the number between j and k generally does not provide much information about the matches between i and k. (Sometimes it does; if the i-j (or j-k) comparison is full of matches, then the relationship is transitive: the i-k count equals the j-k (or i-j) count. But that does not help the general case.)

Comment: Is the segment length always eight? What can it range to? How does it vary—is there a particular length of interest for a particular set of data, or do answers need to be available for all lengths in a range?

Comment: What is going to be done with this data—why are you compiling information on the numbers of matches?

Comment: Thanks, Eric. The length is a particular number as the parameter. The output score matrix is going to perform graph finding in my next steps.